# Creating a Function to Count Unique Values Based on Another Column

Tags: python, pandas, function, unique-values

I have data that look like this.

| company_name | new_company_status |
| --- | --- |
| A Co.,Ltd | Yes |
| B. Inc | No |
| PT XYZ | No |
| PT DFE, Tbk. | Yes |
| A Co.,Ltd | Yes |
| PT DFE, Tbk. | Yes |

I want to create a function in python to check every unique company name from 'company_name' column and compare the 'new_company_status', if the 'new_company_status' is "Yes" for every unique company name, it will count as 1 and iterate to get the total number of new company.

So far this is the code that I write:
`

```
def new_comp(DataFrame):
    comp_list = df['Company_Name'].values.tolist
    uniq_comp = set(comp_list)
    for x in uniq_comp:
        if df['Status_New_Company'] == "Yes":
            uniq_comp += 1
    print('New Companies: ', uniq_comp)
```

`

Can anyone help me to complete and/or revise the code? I expect the output is integer to define the total of new company. Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use masks and boolean addition to count the matches:

```
# keep one company of each
m1 = ~df['company_name'].duplicated()
# is this a yes?
m2 = df['new_company_status'].eq('Yes')

# count cases for which both conditions are True
out = (m1&m2).sum()
```

Output: `2`

If a given company can have both Yes and No and you want to count 1 if there is at least one Yes, you can use a [`groupby.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html):

```
out = (df['new_company_status']
  .eq('Yes')
 .groupby(df['company_name']).any()
 .sum()
)
```

Output: `2`

Answer (score 0):

If need total unique values of `company_name` if `new_company_status` match `Yes` filter and count length of sets:

```
N = len(set(df.loc[df['new_company_status'].eq('Yes'), 'company_name']))
```

If need count number of `Yes` per `company_name` to new DataFrame aggregate boolean mask by `sum`:

```
df1 = (df['new_company_status'].eq('Yes')
                .groupby(df['company_name'])
                .sum()
                .reset_index(name='countYes'))
```